# Allowing multiple correct answers in a multiple-choice quiz | Angular.js & JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, json

I'm all very new to this stuff - so apologies if this is a silly question.

I've created a multiple-choice quiz using HTML, CSS, JavaScript (angular.js), and a JSON data file; off a tutorial I found. I am rather pleased with how it turned out; but I really need to add the functionality of having the user select more than one answer for the question to be marked as correct. How can this be done? Is it simply a case of marking more than one correct answer in the JSON file?

I appreciate any help!

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html ng-app="myQuiz">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test Your Knowledge: Saturn</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="myQuiz" ng-controller="QuizController">
        <h1>Test your Knowledge: <span>Planets</span></h1>

        <div class="progress">
            <div class="
            {{ ($index===activeQuestion)? 'on' : 'off' }}
            {{ (myQuestion.questionState==='answered') ? 'answered':'unanswered'}}
            {{ (myQuestion.correctness==='correct') ? 'correct':'incorrect'}}
            " ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="intro {{ (activeQuestion > -1 ? 'inactive' : 'active') }}">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
            <p>Click begin to start a topic</p>
            <p class="btn" ng-click="activeQuestion = 0">Begin</p>
        </div>


        <div class="question
        {{$index === activeQuestion ? 'active' : 'inactive'}}
        {{myQuestion.questionState === 'answered' ? 'answered' : 'unanswered'}}
        " ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
            <p class="txt">{{myQuestion.question}}</p>
            <p class="ans"
                ng-class="{
                    image: Answer.image,
                    selected: isSelected($parent.$index,$index),
                    correct : isCorrect($parent.$index,$index)
                }"
                ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url({{Answer.image}})'}"
                ng-click="selectAnswer($parent.$index,$index)"
                ng-repeat="Answer in myQuestions[$index].answers">
                {{Answer.text}}
            </p>

            <div class="feedback">
                <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'correct'">You are <strong>correct</strong>.</p>
                <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'incorrect'">Oops! That is not correct.</p>
                <p>{{myQuestion.feedback}}</p>
                <div class="btn" ng-click="selectContinue()">Continue</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="results {{ (totalQuestions===activeQuestion) ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}">
            <h3>Results</h3>
            <p>You scored {{percentage}}% by correctly answering {{score}} of the total {{totalQuestions}} questions.</p>
            <p>Use the links below to challenge your friends.</p>
            <div class="share" ng-bind-html="createShareLinks(percentage)">
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JSON (there is more than one question - but they're all in this format.

```
[{
    "question" : "What is the name of Saturn's largest moon?",
    "answers"  : [
        {"id"  : 0, "text" : "Hercules"},
        {"id"  : 1, "text" : "Europa"},
        {"id"  : 2, "text" : "Goliath"},
        {"id"  : 3, "text" : "Zeus"},
        {"id"  : 4, "text" : "Titan"},
        {"id"  : 5, "text" : "Triton"}
    ],
    "correct"  : 4,
    "feedback" : "Though the names seem similar, Triton orbits the planet Neptune."
}]
```

JavaScript

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myQuiz',[]);
app.controller('QuizController'['$scope','$http','$sce',function($scope,$http,$sce){

$scope.score = 0;
$scope.activeQuestion = -1;
$scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
$scope.percentage = 0;

$http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
  $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
  $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
});

$scope.selectAnswer = function(qIndex,aIndex){
  var questionState = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState;
  if(questionState != 'answered'){
    $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].selectedAnswer = aIndex;
    var correctAnswer = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correct;
    $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer = correctAnswer;

    if(aIndex === correctAnswer){
      $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = 'correct';
      $scope.score += 1;
    }else{
      $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = 'incorrect';
    }
    $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState = 'answered';
  }
  $scope.percentage = (($scope.score / $scope.totalQuestions)*100).toFixed(1);
}

$scope.isSelected = function(qIndex, aIndex){
    return $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].selectedAnswer === aIndex;
}
$scope.isCorrect = function(qIndex, aIndex){
    return $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer === aIndex;
}
$scope.selectContinue = function(qIndex, aIndex){
    return $scope.activeQuestion += 1;
}

$scope.createShareLinks=function(percentage){
  var url = 'http://theoryquiz.com';

  var emailLink = '<a class="btn email" href="mailto:?subject=Try to beat my score!&amp;body= I scored '+percentage+'% on this quiz! Try to beat my score at '+url+'."> Email a Friend </a>';
  var twitterLink = '<a class="btn twitter" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=I scored '+percentage+' on this quiz. Try to beat my score at &amp;hashtags=TheoryQuiz&url='+url+'"> Tweet your score </a>';
  var newMarkup = emailLink + twitterLink;
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(newMarkup);}}]);})();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved with the following:

```
  var superbag = function(sup, sub) {
sup.sort();
sub.sort();
var i, j;
for (i=0,j=0; i<sup.length && j<sub.length;) {
    if (sup[i] < sub[j]) {
        ++i;
    } else if (sup[i] == sub[j]) {
        ++i; ++j;
    } else {
        // sub[j] not in sup, so sub not subbag
        return false;
    }
}
// make sure there are no elements left in sub
return j == sub.length;}
var contains = function(needle) {
// Per spec, the way to identify NaN is that it is not equal to itself
var findNaN = needle !== needle;
var indexOf;

if(!findNaN && typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === 'function') {
    indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;
} else {
    indexOf = function(needle) {
        var i = -1, index = -1;

        for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            var item = this[i];

            if((findNaN && item !== item) || item === needle) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return index;
    };
}

return indexOf.call(this, needle) > -1;};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can achieve this.

I would just give you the direct solution (as I'm sure someone else will), but I think there's a lot of benefit in figuring it out yourself with the right guidance, especially given that you are "new", as you claim. :)

**Here is one approach you can take**:

Create a "store" of answers in memory to check against

- When someone checks a checkbox, check that question and answer against the store.
- If the question in the store contains an answer that was selected, we have a winner. Otherwise, we have a loser.

Example:

```
var questions = {
    "question1": ["answer1", "answer2"],
    "question2": ["answer1", "answer3", "answer3"]
};

function selectAnswer(question, selectedAnswer) {
    if (questions[question]) {
        var found = false;

        questions[question].forEach(function (answer) {
            if (answer === selectedAnswer) {
                found = true;
            }
        });

        if (found) {
            // Do something
        }

        return found;
    }
}

console.log(selectAnswer("question1", "answer1")) // true
console.log(selectAnswer("question1", "answer4")) // false
```

Now you can expand on that function by making it take in an argument of a list of answers instead of just one answer, and you can check all answers against the store for a particular question. OR, you can use that one function against each answer that was selected for a given question. That works as well.

That should achieve what you want! :)

---

If all fails and you still need help, feel free to leave a comment and I'll cook something up for your specific environment (Angular, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! I'll try and find something that works. If not, I'll certainly come back!

Answer (score 1):

You should change your json "correct: field to be an array of ids.

If your question has only one answer, the array will just contain one element.

If Your question has several answer, you just have to modify your javascript function selectAnswer() to handle an array instead of a single value.

Small tip: for your "correctness" and "answered" field, I would use a boolean instead of a string